# Why there is no background after reduce the width of window?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know, why there is no wooden background in the upper right corner after reduce the width of window on http://www.checkitout.over.cz

Thanks to all.

Comment: What browser does this happen on? Which ones have you tried?

Comment: This fact appears on all major browsers. I see brown color instead of wooden background. But only in the upper right corner.

Comment: making the webpage responsive would fix the issue, basically the issue your having is when overflowing #wrapper is bigger than #container hence why the background ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `#container` element is getting it’s with from the viewport, but it contains an element with a `min-width` which will flow out of the `#container`. A quick way to fix this is to give the `#container` the same `min-width`:

```
#container {
    min-width : 1000px;
}
```